# Java SQL Auto Increment

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to create a new table in my SQLite database using Java. It's giving me the same error over and over and I'm getting extremely frustrated by it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        try {
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();

            s.execute(
                    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Loot (" +
                    "LootID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT," +
                    "Chance INT NOT NULL," +
                    "Material VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL" +
                    ")"
            );

            s.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The error I'm receiving:

````
[17:19:01 WARN]: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error)
[17:19:01 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
[17:19:01 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
[17:19:01 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374)
[17:19:01 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
[17:19:01 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123)
[17:19:01 WARN]:        at org.sqlite.Stmt.execute(Stmt.java:113)```
````

Comment: It is AUTOINCREMENT  and not AUTO_INCREMENT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your execute to this:

```
       s.execute(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Loot (" +
                "LootID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "Chance INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                "Material VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL" +
                ")"
        );
```

Please also take time to review https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html to understand whether you will need a specific autoincrement column or not. ROWID might be sufficient enough for you.

Let's say you didn't have LootID as the autoincrementing field, and instead had a table like this:

```
create table loot (chance, material);
insert into loot values ('good', 'copper');
insert into loot values ('bad', 'iron');
```

Your table will have an autoincrementing column called ROWID by default. So you can do this:

```
select rowid, * from loot;
rowid       chance      material  
----------  ----------  ----------
1           good        copper    
2           bad         iron
```

This may or may not be something you might already know, so I thought I'd let you know about the existence of ROWID.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Please use the following code :**

***Change in the Code - AUTO_INCREMENT to AUTOINCREMENT***

```
try {
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();

            s.execute(
                    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Loot (" +
                    "LootID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    "Chance INT NOT NULL," +
                    "Material VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL" +
                    ")"
            );

            s.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just FYI - I noticed that `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Loot (LootID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Chance INT NOT NULL,Material VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);` throws an error `Error: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` on SQLite version 3.28.0. Using `INTEGER` instead of `INT` datatype solves that error. +1 to you for detecting the problem.